# Google Cloud Functions - access to key's value

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to return a value out of an array of values I get from querying Datastore.

results[0] have this content: {"prod_name":"Muffin","prod_price":3.99}.

I'd like to return via res.send only: 3.99

I've tried results[0].prod_price, or results[0]['prod_price'], I have tried saving results[0] as variable and trying to return prod_price, but nothing works. 
Any help is appreciated.

My code is here:

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Instantiates a client
const datastore = Datastore();
const storage = new Storage();
exports.getprice = function getprice (req, res) {
  const kind = datastore.createQuery("Dialogflow");
  const filter = kind.filter("prod_name", req.body.queryResult.parameters['bakery_items']);     
  return query = datastore.runQuery(kind)
    .then( (results) => {
      const entities = results[0];
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
      res.send(JSON.stringify({ "fulfillmentText": entities}));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

Actually I kept results instead of forcing `results[0]`, and realized the output had an extra array, so to access the value, I had to do: `results[0][0]['prod_price']`

Thanks to JavaScript console.

Comment: I need to return the entire object. Do you know how we can do this ? I tried but the service response: "Error: incorrect function response." my code is loke yours:                                      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
      res.send(JSON.stringify({ "fulfillmentText": entities}));